# How to Display Last rolling 12 months in correct month order

Tags: t-sql, ssrs-2008-r2, columnsorting

I have an SSRS report that shows customer sales for the year and I have been asked to change it to the last 13 rolling months. I have changed my where clause to be:

```
WHERE (#First12Months.FirstSaleDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MM,-13,@ReportDate) AND (@ReportDate))
```

*( @ReportDate is the last day of the month that needs to be displayed on the right of the matrix.)*

This where clause pulls the correct data but it is still displaying in my monthsort order and I need to change this to the last 12 months so that the newest month is on the right and the oldest month is on the left.  I cannot work out how to do the sort.
My old sort is MonthSort which gives each month a number where April is 1 through to March = 12:

```
CASE WHEN Month(#First12Months.FirstSaleDate)<=3 THEN MONTH(#First12Months.FirstSaleDate)+9 ELSE MONTH(#First12Months.FirstSaleDate)-3 END AS MonthSort
```

but of course this is now incorrect as I need the month from @ReportDate to be number 13 and each month before that chronologically to be 1 number less.

I found this post which is the only one that seems to come close to what I need but unfortunately I simply don't understand what it is saying.

[Dynamic table/output each month for report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41941099/dynamic-table-output-each-month-for-report)

How do I tell the MonthSort column which number to allocate to the months to get the correct sort order for a rolling 13 months?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your data is in rows and your SSRS displays it in columns you can do the following:
Add a sorting column to your sql query that uses an [analytical function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in order to give the (dense) rank of the month. That rank can then be used as a sorting criteria in SSRS.

Assuming your month column is called `month`, your query could look like this:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by month) rnk from t
```

That order could also be done descending like this:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by month desc) rnk from t
```

Let's have an example:

```
with t as (
select 2134 sales, cast('20190101' as date) month union all
select 3456 sales, cast('20190201' as date) month union all
select 234 sales, cast('20190301' as date) month union all
select 4567 sales, cast('20190401' as date) month union all
select 5678 sales, cast('20190501' as date) month union all
select 234 sales, cast('20190601' as date) month union all
select 756 sales, cast('20190701' as date) month union all
select 9 sales, cast('20190801' as date) month union all
select 24356134 sales, cast('20190901' as date) month union all
select 2456134 sales, cast('20191001' as date) month union all
select 234 sales, cast('20191101' as date) month union all
select 675 sales, cast('20191201' as date) month union all
select 86 sales, cast('20200101' as date) month union all
select 786 sales, cast('20200201' as date) month union all
select 715 sales, cast('20200301' as date) month union all
select 156 sales, cast('20200401' as date) month union all
select 123 sales, cast('20200501' as date) month union all
select 687 sales, cast('20200601' as date) month union all
select 45 sales, cast('20200701' as date) month
)
, t1 as (
select sales, month from t where t.month > dateadd(MONTH, -12, getdate())
)
select t1.*, DENSE_RANK() over (order by datefromparts(year(month), month([month]), 1)) rnk from t1
```

will return
[image]

Comment: Thank you @casenonsensitive this was a very useful link but unfortunately I could not work out how to tell it where to start each month to account for the rolling month change

Comment: The dense_rank will return numbers starting from 1. So let's assume there are twelve different month, then dense_rank will return 1 to 12, depending on the order of the month.

Comment: Maybe I am being really thick here @casenonsensitive but I still don't understand how to use 'dense_rank() over'  to start the ranking at a different month each time.  Thank you for your help and I am sorry that I can't follow the reasoning.

Comment: Thank you I understand now - it uses the month and year from the data in the data set and ranks it by the month and year making it dynamic.  The rnk number can then be used to sort the column group

Comment: Thank you for all of your help.  I still was not able to get the  DENSE_RANK() over (order by month) to rank by the month of the sale date correctly. That may have been my inexperience showing (it was ranking by every day).  I have run out of time and therefore have marked my own answer as correct as that has worked for me, however for anyone else reading this post this may also be a correct answer.

Comment: " That may have been my inexperience showing (it was ranking by every day)." - in my comment above should read (it was ranking the same month for 2019 and 2020 as the same number)

Comment: Of course the date needs to adapted. Meaning one different date per month. Like this: datefromparts(year(date), month(date), 1). I'll adapt the answer.

Comment: Thank you @casenonsensitive that has really helped - will now mark this as the correct answer as it is better than my effort below

Answer (score 0):

I guess, your first query retrieving the data is correct. Changing the columns' order would have to be done in the SSRS report.
For sorting tablix (table elements in SSRS) have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/sort-data-in-a-data-region-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer but in the question you will see that I already know how to do normal column sorting and have already been using the method detailed above.  I just need some help in working out how to allocate the numbers to sort by which would be in the SQL I would imagine. Or I need someone to explain in simpler terms the post that I linked in my question.

Comment: Assuming your table contains a month for the sales you can use an analytical function on the sql server in order to get an ordering column that you would use in SSRS. Here's an example: select month, DENSE_RANK() over (order by month) dr from t   Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 for the details on the sql server.

Comment: Thank you @casenonsensitive - could you post your last response as a separate answer to my original comment so that if it proves to be the answer I can mark it as correct - it would not be right to mark your original comment as correct

Answer (score 0):

Posting my own answer:
I have managed to work out a formula that calculates a position number for each column to replace my MonthSort column:

```
select case when MONTH(saledate) BETWEEN MONTH(dateadd(mm,-11,@ReportDate)) AND 12 THEN((MONTH(saledate)+1)-MONTH(@ReportDate)+11) ELSE ((month(saledate)+1)+month(@ReportDate)+11) end as position,
from table
WHERE (saledate BETWEEN DATEADD(MM,-11,@ReportDate) AND (@ReportDate))
```

This doesn't quite give me what I wanted as I wanted 12 months but couldn't work out how to differentiate between the same month this year and the same month last year e.g. if the report date is 30/6/2020 then with a 12 month parameter it gives 2 June months (1 for each year 2019 and 2020) but places both of them in position 1 when June 2019 should be in position 1 and June 2020 should be in position 13.  Works well with 11 months.  If anyone can help with getting it to 12 months I would be grateful

Comment: For my particular question this was the best answer although the response from @casenonsensitive was very helpful I couldn't get it to work as I wanted it to in this instance.

Comment: @casenonsensitive has adapted the answer so that is now the best reponse to my query

Answer (score 0):

I am posting another answer of my own because it is a different way of achieving what I needed as well as the simplest - I was making this issue far more complicated than it needed to be.
In my second effort I added an extra column called SaleYear using: YEAR(SaleDate).  I already had a column for MONTH(SaleDate) that I was using in a case when to achieve the Apr to March sort.
I restricted the data within the SQL query to the last 13 months using a where clause:

```
WHERE (SaleDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MM,-13,@ReportDate) AND DATEADD(minute, - 1, @ReportDate + 1))
```

And in the SSRS report I added 'Year' as a parent column group to the 'Month' column group.  In the column group I added sorting by Year and then by month.
Because I had already restricted the data in the sql query to the last 13 months I have the last 13 rolling months in the correct order.

This is the cleanest and most simplistic answer.